# convert ancient dvi file that uses special fonts to pdf?

Tags: fonts, dvips

I have a dvi file from 1989 that uses special fonts. The dvi file was created from LaTeX. I saved all of the LaTeX source, all of the .tfm files, all of the .pk files, all of the .pxl files, and all of the .1500pxl files. I also saved the shell scripts that generated everything.

I'd like to convert the document to modern pdf.

The shell scripts use a command:

dvi2ps -a /tx/qobi/tex/pxlfonts -a /usr/lib/tex/pxlfonts.canon smthesisfrag

I no longer have dvi2ps. I have dvips instead. But dvips doesn't accept the -a argument. I can't figure out from the man page, the --help, or the online document what the equivalent of the -a argument is, i.e. how one specifies a directory with .pk, .pxl, and .1500pxl files.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: if it's just a one off you could simply copy them to the local directory

Comment: just tried that. didn't work

Comment: qobi@ym>ls -l heb10.*
-rw------- 1 qobi qobi 6956 Mar 19 13:22 heb10.1500pxl
-rw------- 1 qobi qobi 1444 Mar 19 13:22 heb10.pk
-rw------- 1 qobi qobi 6956 Mar 19 13:22 heb10.pxl
-rw------- 1 qobi qobi  712 Mar 19 13:22 heb10.tfm
qobi@ym>ls -l hebs10.*
-rw------- 1 qobi qobi 7192 Mar 19 13:22 hebs10.1500pxl
-rw------- 1 qobi qobi 1896 Mar 19 13:22 hebs10.pk
-rw------- 1 qobi qobi 7192 Mar 19 13:22 hebs10.pxl
-rw------- 1 qobi qobi  712 Mar 19 13:22 hebs10.tfm
qobi@ym>dvips -o smthesis.ps -M smthesis.dvi

Comment: dvips: Font heb10 not found; using cmr10

Comment: dvips: Font hebs10 not found; using cmr10

Comment: try dvips -d -1 to turn on debugging (texdoc dvips page 9)  it will tell you where it is looking...

Comment: worked, thanks, fonts need to be in a dpi300 or whatever subdirectory

Comment: since you have a working setup, can you post a self answer? thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to David Carlisle.

The simple solution is to:

1. make a dpi300 (change resolution as appropriate) subdirectory in the directory that 
   has the dvi file; put the .pk and .pxl files in that subdirectory
2. run dvips with -M -X 300 -Y 300 (change resolution as appropriate)

You can figure out where dvips tries to find various files by giving it the -d -1 option as the first on the command line.

Comment: You can accept your answer so it drops from unanswered list (you may even get the badge :-)